# how to call the handler from another application?

Tags: python, django-cms

please help to solve the problem.

using django-cms. created a separate application app_feedback.

views.py:

```
def feedback(request):
    '''
    TODO: form handler. post data
    '''
    print('fffed')  

    return
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('app_feedback',
    url(r'^/$', 'views.feedback', name='feedback'),

)
```

then basically template django-cms made ​​form:

```
<form class="feedback_form common_form" id="feedbackForm" action="/feedback/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input id="id_author" maxlength="100" name="author" type="text">
    <input class="btn btn-default" id="submitFeedback" type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # NOQA
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap',
        {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
    url(r'feedback/', include('app_feedback.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

The problem is that after a form is loaded in the browser address:

```
http://localhost:8000/ru/feedback/
```

console displays:

```
Not Found: /feedback/
[31/Oct/2014 14:21:39] "POST /feedback/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Not Found: /ru/feedback/
[31/Oct/2014 14:21:39] "GET /ru/feedback/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3113
```

log displays:

```
Not Found: /ru/feedback/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex in your included url should be just `r'^$'`, without the slash.